# Laravel Excel Img src not working from storage

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to export excel with images but I have this error.

> (1/1) PHPExcel_Exception File
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/3x1HVvwYYNXAZxc/1.jpg not found!

When I press the link it shows the photo.

My controller:

```
public function WholeSaleStockExport(Request $request, BidFilters $filters)
    {
        Excel::create('name: ' . date("Y/m/d"), function($excel ) use($filters, $request) {
            $excel->sheet('today', function($sheet)  use($filters, $request) {

                $bid = ClientCar::filter($filters)->orderBy('lot_date', 'ASC')->get();
                $sheet->loadView('manager.sheets.wholesale', array('cars' => $bid));
            });
        })->download('xls');
    }
```

in my view i have this:

```
<img src="{{  asset('/storage/photos/') . '/' . $car->lot_id . '/' . '1.jpg' }}" width="80px">
```

How can I solve this problem?